# Strange behaviour with Osmdroid overlay at high zoom levels

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm using the osmdroid 3.0.5 jar in my app to display a map view. I'm superimposing an overlay, consisting of horizontal and vertical lines. I've noticed that in certain locations only, at high zoom levels some of the lines disappear, then reappear as the map is dragged.

I've produced a minimal sample app which demonstrates the problem which exhibits itself both on a real device and an emulator (Gingerbread 2.3.3).

The complete code is shown below - (the 'transform' methods are necessary in the real app although they don't appear to be in this minimal sample) :

```
public class DemoMap extends Activity implements MapViewConstants {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    private MapOverlay mmapOverlay = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.copymain);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(17);
        // Only shows the bug at ceratin lat/lon positions, this is one
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(39191699, -120102561);
        mapController.setCenter(point2);
        mmapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this);
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.add(mmapOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    public class MapOverlay extends org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay {

        public MapOverlay(Context ctx) {super(ctx); }

        private int mVpl;// viewport left, top, right, bottom
        private int mVpt;
        private int mVpr;
        private int mVpb;
        private MapView mMv = null;

        // Two routines to transform and scale between viewport and mapview
        private float transformX(float in, MapView mv) {
            float out;
            out = ((mVpr - mVpl) * in) / (mv.getRight() - mv.getLeft())
                    + mVpl;
            return out;
        }

        private float transformY(float in, MapView mv) {
            float out;
            out = ((mVpb - mVpt) * in) / (mv.getBottom() - mv.getTop())
                    + mVpt;
            return out;
        }

        @Override
        protected void draw(Canvas pC, MapView mapV, boolean shadow) {
            if (shadow)
                return;

            Paint paint;
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            paint.setTextSize(12);
            final Rect viewportRect = new Rect();
            final Projection projection = mapV.getProjection();
            viewportRect.set(projection.getScreenRect());
            mVpl = viewportRect.left;
            mVpt = viewportRect.top;
            mVpr = viewportRect.right;
            mVpb = viewportRect.bottom;
            // draw two lines to split screen into 2x2 quarters
            // drag the map left and right and the vertical line disappears,
            // then reappears! It's OK at one less zoom level
            pC.drawLine(transformX(mapV.getWidth()/2, mapV), transformY(0, mapV),
                    transformX(mapV.getWidth()/2, mapV),
                    transformY(mapV.getHeight(), mapV), paint);

            pC.drawLine(transformX(0, mapV), transformY(mapV.getHeight()/2, mapV),
                    transformX(mapV.getWidth(), mapV),
                    transformY(mapV.getHeight()/2, mapV), paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly if, in my real app, if I do the drawing to an offscreen bitmap, then draw it all in one go at the end of the Overlay's draw, it's OK the lines don't disappear.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I believe what you're experiencing is [Issue 221](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=221). This has been fixed in version 3.0.9.

Also see: [OSMDroid PathOverlay drawing is corrupted at high zoom levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273561/osmdroid-pathoverlay-drawing-is-corrupted-at-high-zoom-levels)

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'd be quite keen to try the new jar but I don't know how to get the javadocs jar  to give me the context assist help in Eclipse. There don't seem to be any since 3.0.7

Comment: We should post a new javadoc build alongside new releases. I will add an issue report. Note that you can also build your own using maven.

Comment: FYI - javadoc can be downloaded from Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-2035155240

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately I can't get Eclipse/SDK to giver hover assist anymore with this one. You have to add a reference to the jar in libs\jarname.properties. What I had to do with 3.0.5 was rename the javadoc jar to .zip, expand it and reference that in the properties file. That worked Ok, not so for 3.0.9. They really broke Eclipse and javadocs with SDK17! There's no longer any option to  have Eclipse validate the javadoc file so I think I'll have to stay with 3.0.5, thanks anyway.

Comment: Update: If I add the sources.jar as well and reference it in osmdroid-android-3.0.9.jar.properties, then the javadocs show up in the hover, so all OK. (Except one has to have a separate copy of the jar for every single project, but that's just Android SDK madness!)

Comment: I found the original test project and replaced 3.0.5 with 3.0.9. This was the only change. I'm sorry to say that the problem is still there. I can see no discernible difference in behaviour. I used the code as shown in the original question. I see the same behaviour on a 2.1 emulator and a Jelly Bean Samsung Galaxy S2

Comment: Your overlay must extend SafeDrawOverlay to take advantage of the new drawing fixes. Move your draw code into the safeDraw() method and you shouldn't have to make any more changes beyond that.

Comment: It works thank you. I changed everything that needed to be a 'safe' method/class i.e Overlay, draw, Canvas and Paint and the test code is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may be another manifestation of this bug:
[Issue 207](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=207&q=high%20zoom)

Do you see the same behaviour with earlier API versions?

Comment: Possibly it is. I think I will try it on an API 7 emulator, thanks

Comment: I rebuilt it using API7 and Osmdroid 3.0.3 and ran it on an API 7 emulator. The problem is still there. Those are the earliest versions I can use. The bitmap solution works OK, but I'm always wary of leaking memory as I've not much experience with bitmaps

Comment: Reading 207 this shounds to be different that has nothing realy to di with overlays just standard tiles in the cache.